# How to change the uinavigationbar title's position?

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, material-design

I've managed to change the navigationbar height by using my own navigationbar, but the title is still centered. I want it to be at the 72px position from the left.

```
override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
   return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 56)
}
```

I used this to change the height but I didn't find a way to change the position of all the items.
I tried to set the frame but I can't. I can't change the position of the button too.

i wanna look like this

[image]

Comment: Add empty navigation bar button item as a right bar button item and set it's width as per your requirement. It moves your title left side.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a `UIView` object add `UIButton` and `UILabel` in it to show a similar view. Add this custom view into left bar button item of navigation controller.

An example screen shot to visualise a custom view and related code:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 44.0))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    var button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "hamburger"), for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 5.0, width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuOpen(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    customView.addSubview(button)

    var marginX = CGFloat(button.frame.origin.x + button.frame.size.width + 5)
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: marginX, y: 0.0, width: 65.0, height: 44.0))
    label.text = "Inbox"
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    customView.addSubview(label)

    var leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
}

func menuOpen(button: UIButton) {
    // Handle menu button event here...
}
```

Comment: thanks! its a good solution but i just found out that google isn't using the navigationController it's simply a normal view.And i will try ur method later~

Answer (score 30):

```
navBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(7), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: This answer only addresses the vertical position of the item. How does this answer the question which is asking about adjusting the horizontal position?

Comment: @TonyAdams I guess I didn't know the answer for the question back then so I just threw something in the air that could help others...

Comment: COOL! THAT IS WHAT I NEED!!

Comment: This only used when you want to change the position of title in vertically. to change the horizontally there is no predefined option. so you can follow the first answer to this question is a better solution.

Comment: This "works" in iOS 16.0 + Xcode 14.0. But it throws an error for broken constraints. "_UINavigationBarTitleControl should equal titleViewGuide.top". Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can also set nav bar appearance `titlePositionAdjustment` like so:

```
let a = UINavigationBarAppearance()
a.titlePositionAdjustment = .init(
   horizontal: -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, 
   vertical: 0
)
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = a
navigationItem.compactAppearance = a
navigationItem.standardAppearance = a
```

Comment: This is the best answer and doesn't cause any issues like setting anchors on the title did.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to simply indent the title:

```swift
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 72

navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.purple,
    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting custom view with left align.

Setting custom view as leftBarButtonItem is not conveniently, because we will have a problems with back button.

Setting custom view as subview of navigationBar is not conveniently because:

- we can't to easy control width of custom view when right buttons are set. We can get overlapping custom view and right buttons
- we need to add custom navTitleView and remove it every viewWillAppear and viewWillDissapear. This is additional, not clean code.

So?
I've just added width constraint to the customTitleView.

Inside of CustomTitleView class:

```
  private func layoutViewsConfig() {
    // Width constraint needed to align view to left
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    widthConstraint.priority = .init(748)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
   self.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
   self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)    
  }
```

Then, inside of your ViewController:

```
var navigationTitleView = NavigationSubtitleView() 
self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationTitleView
```

And we have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom view as the left/right bar item of the navigationItem.

See this example:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewModal.getNavBarTitleView())
```

[The `viewModal.getNavBarTitleView()` returns an horizontal stack view with an imageView and a label.]