# iOS top bar not showing

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to show a top bar in Xcode 9 Swift 4. In my storyboard it shows the top bar as in the below picture:

[image: storyboard top bar]

but when I run it I get this with no top bar:

[image]

I tried to use a navigation bar just with a title but it shows as:

[image]

the carrier, wifi, time, and battery background is still white. If I set the navigation bar to the top of the screen, it will cover them like:

[image]

Why the top bar is not showing? How can achieve something like this?:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Top bar is not a navigation bar. It is kind of just a bar that shows a title. As you can see in the below picture, the register scene doesn't have a navigation bar. I added the top bar from the properties on the right side.

[image]

Comment: I don't even know what the thing you so-call 'top var' is.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by top bar? Is it the status bar or the black navigation bar?

Comment: @ElTomato updated

Comment: @ch1maera updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the code from @Milan Nosáľ answer and it does show the status in white. Then used @Ameya Vichare answer on this link while I was looking for a way to increase the navigation bar height
[How to change navigationBar height in iOS 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138245/how-to-change-navigationbar-height-in-ios-11/46138389?noredirect=1) turn out it is a bug in Xcode 9. Now it shows like what I wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your second to last screen, where you show that the navigation bar covers it:

[image]

It does not really cover it - but the text of the status bar is black, so you cannot see it. To change it, in the implementation of the `GrolocationNewsViewController` (or whatever you call it) override `preferredStatusBarStyle` and return `.lightContent`:

```
class GrolocationNewsViewController: UIViewController {

    // rest of the code

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right I used your code and it shows the status in white!

Comment: @JumanaAlhaddad then accept the answer, and if you want to deal with the height of the navigation bar, create a new question