# Change tintcolor of UIBarButton with UIButton as its customview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, tint

I'm creating an UIBarbutton item as below

```
func createNavigationButton(_ btnImage: UIImage, btnAction: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(btnImage, for: UIControl.State())
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: btnAction, for: .touchUpInside)
    let item = UIBarButtonItem()
    item.customView = btn
    item.tintColor = .red
    return item
}
```

Tint color is not changing.

If I create simply like

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: btnImage,
                                    style: .plain,
                                    target: self,
                                    action: btnAction)
item.tintColor = .red
```

Tint color is now changing. But, I need an UIbutton as customview for my barbuttons for some reasons.

How can I change the tintcolor of UIBarbuttonItem with UIbutton as its customview?

Comment: did you try  `btn.tinitColor` ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539067/how-to-change-the-uinavigationbar-titles-position/27544998#27544998, may be it will help

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, yes I tried tintcolor for btn. its not working

Comment: @Kampai, that's a different issue. not about tint color.

Comment: What about barTintColor of navigation bar ?

Comment: And replace this `btn.setImage(btnImage, for: UIControl.State())` with `btn.setImage(btnImage, for: .normal)`

Comment: is your `btnImage` rendered as template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to instantiate the button using the `system` type to be able to set the tint color. Then set the tint color to the btn itself.

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
btn.tintColor = .red
```

---

Or, you can force the rendering mode on your `UIImage`.

```
btn.setImage(btnImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControl.State())
btn.tintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use image as template image: `UIImage(named: "nameOfTheImage")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`
2. You have to set the buttons tint color if the image is on the button.

   `func createNavigationButton(_ btnImage: UIImage, btnAction: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
       let btn = UIButton()
       btn.setImage(btnImage, for: UIControl.State())
       btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
       btn.addTarget(self, action: btnAction, for: .touchUpInside)
       btn.tintColor = .red
       let item = UIBarButtonItem()
       item.customView = btn
       item.tintColor = .red
       return item
   }`